# English versus French grammar

Tags: grammar, adjectives, french

Recently, on the internet, I have heard people say that one should conjugate certain adjectives that are closely related to French. For example, blond for males and blonde for females in the singular form. More recently I have heard someone say that certain nouns should be declined for male and female, -I can't think of an example currently, but the declension would be where one would add an extra e and then make the second to last e have an acute.- Is this technically correct, or is it just using French grammar in English?

Comment: Nouns are genderless in English. And we don't use diacritics (which is what I take you meant by "make the second to last have an acute"), unless we're consciously employing a word we recognize as not English (some style guides require that we use italics when we do that).

Comment: My own belief is that we should not look upon English as a discrete entity. It was not something that was handed down from heaven intact with unique rules of its own. It is a product of the Indo-European family of languages. So in any analysis of English we should always have regard to what happens in related languages, especially French from which Norman form much of English derives. So if opportunities arise to add elegance to our writing or speech I think we should always be ready to employ French forms - if they are clearly French by all means use italics.

Comment: @WS2 "*English ... was not something handed down from Heaven intact*" is a strange position to take for a man who stumps for the term "*Received English*" and rails against people who use *diagnose* in a way which wasn't common in 1950s England...

Comment: @DanBron I entirely respect the history of the English language. But what I have said is another thing altogether to making repeated incorrect use of English and then claiming that because someone has said it enough times it must be accepted. My argument is the corollary of the *etymological fallacy*. Most laws have corollaries. Indeed the position I took on *diagnose* is reinforced by the way it is used in other European languages. That is my whole point. English needs to respect the European traditions on which it is founded.

Comment: @WS2 I can't quite grasp that you can use the term "the history of the English language", and even say you respect it, and are therefore *aware that it changes*, and yet not *accept that it changes*. Here in the US there's a certain type of evangelical, fundamentalist Christian who denies the reality of evolution (they believe in a literal Adam & Eve). The weirdest part is they accept what they (erroneously) term *microevolution*, while simultaneously denying that *small changes add up*. Makes no sense at all.

Comment: @DanBron What constitutes “not English” is a very vague notion, but to me, words like _naïve_, _café_, and _fiancé(e)_ (which I’m guessing is probably the word the asker was talking about here) are quite English, even though I write them with diacritics.

Comment: @Janus I never write diacritics, mostly because I'm never sure how I should. And funny, the "fiance" (one e) must be a UK thing. We only have fiancee (two es) here in the US.

Comment: @DanBron I'm not quite sure what it was I said which bears upon evolution, *Adam & Eve*, etc. Hope I didn't give away my mother's maiden name as well.

Comment: @WS2 The connection was your views of English admit big change but resist small change, and the evangelicals' view of evolution admit small change but resist big change. Both of those philosophical approaches baffle me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Another word which has always been used in Britain to indicate a woman's surname at birth is *née* (meaning *born*). I find that even specialist genealogical software, written in America, does not understand this word.

Comment: @WS2 True, but that one is rather invariable. At least I have never seen a man referred to as _né_ something. One of the places where historical gender bias hasn't really been undone yet—I also don't know what I'd call the male equivalent of a maiden name, even though it's not that uncommon these days for a man to take his spouse’s last name (perhaps _bachelor name_?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conjugation is for verbs.  "Sex" (male and female) is a characteristic of living things.  "Gender" (masculine and feminine), the association of words with one sex or the other (or neither) is a characteristic of words in some languages.  Except for pronouns, English doesn't assign a gender to to words, i.e., the language doesn't have different forms for nouns and adjectives based on gender.  Note that this is different from having separate words to describe the sex associated with the word, e.g., "waitress" for a woman who waits tables and "waiter" for a man.

Remember that Abraham Lincoln said in his third inaugural address on March 31, 1872, "You can't trust everything you read on the internet."

Comment: That's ridiculous! Lincoln *never* said such a thing. It was Benjamin Franklin.

Comment: I'm quite sure it was Plato.

Comment: **However,** some loanwords like *fiancé/fiancée* **are** differentiated in the way Morella asks about.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I've never encountered the word *fiance* with one e. Here in the U.S. At least, both the prospective bride & groom call each other their *fiancee* (with two es).

Comment: And the bride's dad is the *financer*.

Comment: @DanBron [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fiancé) [disagrees](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fiancée) (as does the American Heritage Dictionary). I have absolutely seen Americans use _fiance/fiancé_ with one e when referring to male entities.

Comment: @AndrewLeach But _fiancé(e)_ (for those who make the distinction) is really no different from _waiter/waitress_ or _man/woman_. They’re just different words, not gender-based declensions of a word. _Blond(e)_ is, but it’s my experience that that distinction is vanishing.

Comment: Certainly, the *fiancé/fiancée* distinction **does** exist in British English. And I'm not entirely sure they are different words when they mean "affianced partner".

Comment: @AndrewLeach Well, obviously they're not really different words—Dan’s description of common US practice conforms much better to the reality that they're both the same lexeme in speech. But in writing, the distinction is not one of regular suffixation (or suffix change, as the case may be) according to gender as it is in French, but simply one of having two differently spelt words, one of which refers to a man, the other to a woman.

Comment: M-W defines *biscotto* with *biscotti* as the plural. However, the singular I hear is usually biscotti. (When the cashier says "So that's one medium coffee and one biscotti," I do my best not to reveal an inner cringe--I lived in Italy for 25 years.) And I see in print: *To test for doneness, remove one biscotti from the oven and place it on your work surface for about 5 minutes to cool down.* Of course we use and adapt words as we please; dictionaries lag.

Comment: ... And 'confetto', and 'confetti are', are rare.